# Maintaining SQLConnections

Tags: function-construction, databaselink, sql

I'm using `SQLConnection` to database in repetitive `ScheduledTask`. To prevent creation of new connections, and to maintain binding of connection to same symbol I made the following:

```
If[MatchQ[conn, _SQLConnection],
 If[SQLConnectionOpenQ[conn],
  If[(! SQLConnectionUsableQ[conn]), CloseSQLConnection[conn]; 
   conn = OpenSQLConnection[conn];], conn = OpenSQLConnection[conn];],
  conn = OpenSQLConnection["demo"];]
```

Question:

How to make the same procedure, but with usage of `conn` symbol only on one place, NOT as above with `conn` on 9 places?

**EDIT:** additionally to this question and to the [answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/169518/6226) below given by the [Kuba](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/5478/kuba), emerged new problem and question posted here [SQLConnection causes kernel hangs](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/170176/6226)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Moving my comments into an answer:

If you create `forceConnection[conn_]:=If[..` then you don't have to worry about replacing `conn` inside in future. You need to add `HoldFirst` attribute to `forceConnection` if you want to modify its value.

Additionally, I don't like nested `Ifs`:

```
forceConnection // Attributes = {HoldFirst};

forceConnection[conn_] := conn = Which[
  ! MatchQ[conn, _SQLConnection], OpenSQLConnection["demo"]
, ! SQLConnectionOpenQ[conn],     OpenSQLConnection[conn]
, ! SQLConnectionUsableQ[conn],   CloseSQLConnection[conn]; OpenSQLConnection[conn]
, True,                           conn
]
```

Comment: +1 And gosh, working the WL all this time and I was not aware that one can use postfix notation (aka reverse Polish notation) for setting `Attributes` in this way. :)

Comment: @gwr yes, I like to start 'definition' lines with the symbol name. You can also do `symbol ~ SetAttributes ~ attr` but I don't like it :)

Comment: One has to be aware of `SetAttributes` adding to potentially existing list and `Attributes` resetting it. The devil is in the details as always.

Comment: @Kuba I think that the second test in your function is misleading.  The documentation states that "SQLConnectionOpenQ is strictly a client-side test and initiates no communication with the connection's target server, local or remote."  So, SQLConnectionOpenQ  is not enough to test if the connection is really working.  SQLConnectionUsableQ is much slower but in my opinion has to be part of the test.  One more thing, how do you know if OpenSQLConnection[conn] returns a valid connection?

Comment: @ArielSepulveda Feel free to add an appendix or a separate answer. Your notes make sense but I have no experience with SQLConnection and the answer here addresses a specific idiom and the final function is only a cleaner version of OP's logic.

Comment: @Kuba Your answer is fine but the question is confusing. The function maintainConnection does not ensure a continuous working connection. Indeed, in some situations (e.g. DB server down) it is impossible to ensure a working DB connection.

Comment: @ArielSepulveda after a second look I'm not sure if any changes are needed, except maybe a missing usage message to clarify it. This function does not seem to be a quick check but rather a 'force connection or fail'. Notice that `SQLConnectionOpenQ` is not used to check wheter the connection is ok but as a lightweight check if it is not ok, if it is not, Open- is called, otherwise -UsableQ is called in the same manner. So the `conn` is left only when all checks pass. If any of them fails Open- will fail too when the DB server is down and the function returns $Failed at the end.

Comment: @Kuba You are right. Maybe the function name is the main problem as there’s no way to maintain the connection in all situations. Renaming to checkDBConnection may be more appropriate.

Comment: @ArielSepulveda I renamed it to `forceConnection`, there should be no doubt now.