# SQLConnection causes kernel hangs

Tags: databaselink, scheduling

This question is additional question to [Maintaining SQLConnections](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/169515/maintaining-sqlconnections) In *Mathematica* 10.4.1.0 (64bit).

```
<< DatabaseLink`DatabaseExamples`
DatabaseExamplesBuild[]
Needs["DatabaseLink`"]
Needs["JLink`"]
maintainConnection // Attributes = {HoldFirst};
maintainConnection := conn = OpenSQLConnection["demo"];
t2 := maintainConnection;
t1 := RunScheduledTask[t2; RemoveScheduledTask[$ScheduledTask], {1}]
t1
```

after executing `t1` every expression is executed fully, so `t1`,`t2`,`maintainConnection` and `$ScheduledTask` is removed after it finishes, but kernel stays hanging, and only way is to Quit kernel.
The way to avoid this is to assign `conn = OpenSQLConnection["demo"]` prior the calling `ScheduledTask`, so prior executing `t1`, and after this subsequently call `t2` via Scheduling as needed.
This is most simple example, that, as exposed seem does not have sense, but in complicated where one scheduled task is initiated in another, it does, and in that situation `conn = OpenSQLConnection["demo"]` should be avoided, as a call outside of `t1`, or another `ScheduledTask`.
In *Mathematica* 11.3 this does not cause kernel hangs.

Is this is a bug, or I'm doing something on wrong way?

Comment: Please do not use the [tag:bugs] tag until your observations have been confirmed to be a bug.

Comment: I recommend to use "AutoRemove" -> True instead of removing the task using RemoveScheduledTask inside RunScheduledTask.